# How does NSCollectionView draw text without item?

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

[image]

I've seen a lot of APP listing articles in NSCollectionView. When there is no item, there are some hints in the middle of view, such as "no articles", "waiting to add", and so forth.

Do you have any relevant cases to show me how this is accomplished?.

Thank you

Comment: That's just another view. You should add a new subview if the collection view is empty

Comment: Or a view in front of the collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  func showMessage(_ text: String) {
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    messageLabel.text = text
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = messageLabel
  }

  func hideMessage() {
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil
  }
```